# Convert XML file to CSV with Header in PHP

Tags: php, xml, csv, xml-parsing

Need help to convert this xml file to csv....

```
<DATA>
  <CONTENT data="123456" data1="0"/>
  <CONTENT data="123456" data1="1"/>
  <CONTENT data="123456" data1="0"/>
</DATA>
```

The structure of csv:

```
data,data1
123456,0
123456,1
123456,0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code will convert from XML to CSV, change it to your needs :

```
    <?
$filexml='cars.xml';
if (file_exists($filexml)) {
    $xml = simplexml_load_file($filexml);
$f = fopen('cars.csv', 'w');
foreach ($xml->car as $car) {
    fputcsv($f, get_object_vars($car),',','"');
}
fclose($f);
}
?>
```

In order to customize it to your needs, check out the [fputcsv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php) documentation and [simplexml_load_file](http://php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-file.php) documentation.

Comment: Ok, i have this script working, but not for the format of xml that i have posted, so, what i need to put on foreach ($xml->car as $car) to get the data and data1 ?

Comment: what format does it output? and i've edited the answer with links that will help you solve the problem

Comment: If my solution did it then mark it as answer, if not consider deleting the question or writing your answer of how you resloved it and mark it as an answer.